# Selection exceeds the maximum allowed per request download limit cannot download more than a max of 20 rasters at time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic

Selection exceeds the maximum allowed per request download limit cannot download more than a max of 20 rasters at time

I couldn’t figure out why the when I select more than 20 raster and try to download them form a mosaic dataset I got the following message?!
“Selection exceeds the maximum allowed per request download limit cannot download more than a max of 20 rasters at time”
Is there any method to configure the mosaic to download more than 20 Rasters??

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the service provider has applied this restriction so I suggest that it is they that you should ask.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, its not a web map service its a mosaic dataset which is stored on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in your "Download Properties" for the mosaic dataset. See this link. You will need to set this higher in order to download more than 20. It is in the Defaults tab of the Mosaic Dataset Properties window.

[Mosaic Dataset Download Properties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/mosaic-dataset-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_BF1E997AE794476A923FF66BA3FB3CD3)